# knockout custom binding pass object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a grid control that has a Page X of Y on it. X binds to CurrentPageIndex (CPI). 
a page can have multiple grids, so CPI can be, i.CPI j.CPI, etc.

I've been asked to extend it so that X is either a Span or an Input. currently I have implemented so that:

This works, although I can’t quite get the syntax to use the catch enter key parameter:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: CurrentPageIndex, currentPageIndexInput: 'CatchEnterKey'">
```

The binding currentPageIndexInput blocks non-numeric values and process the enter key.

Then it occurred to me: since this is for the specific control, why not simplify it down to:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="currentPageIndexInput: CurrentPageIndex">
```

I can’t quite find the magic combination to make this work though.  How can I pass in and bind the object CurrentPageIndex to .text?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.currentPageIndexInput = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) 
{
   text : CurrentPageIndex;
}
```

something like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `applyBindingsToNode`

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) 
{
   var currentPageIndex = valueAccessor();
   ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {text: currentPageIndex});
   // ...
}
```